# Pregnant Platty

Tags: fish

I have a female Platty pregnant she was fat when we got her and she has got even fatter. On the bottom of her near her fins I have noticed today there is like a white lump, she is very quiet and stays to herself. I she going to give birth soon. Any help would be great.

Comment: There is a very good answer to a similar question right here: http://pets.stackexchange.com/a/6592