# Can anyone tell me if the think my platy is pregnant?

Tags: fish

[image]

Please can anyone tell me if they think my platy is pregnant?

Comment: Welcome Jayne, maybe this question helps you: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6357/what-are-the-signs-that-a-female-platy-fish-is-about-to-give-birth

Comment: If it has been in a tank with a mature male , it is gravid ( has young developing).