# Pregnant platy fish not releasing fry and developing a white tube gland

Tags: aquarium, fish, breeding, pregnancy, anatomy

I've had my platy fish for 3 weeks and she's pregnant. She squared off last week, as well as developing a white tube/anal gland. I'm just wondering if anyone can help as to when she might release her fry thanks.

[image]

---

[image]

We have baby fry born Friday night/Saturday morning

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the signs that a female platy fish is about to give birth?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6357/what-are-the-signs-that-a-female-platy-fish-is-about-to-give-birth)

Comment: She showing all the signs has been for a few days but not releasing any fry, she constantly trying to hide & not really eating much anymore only odd few bits